# Can't create C# COM DLL. Is it the code? Project properties? Installer properties? 32-64 bit? What?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, com, installation

Goal: Create a C# Assembly called TestDLL.dll that can be installed to any computer such that MS Access VBA can use it via COM.

Environment: 
Windows 7 64-bit.
MS Office Professional Plus 2010 Version: 14.0.1753.5000 (64-bit).
Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

TestDLL.dll assembly code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TestDLL
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("7CAAEF3F-F867-445B-B078-5837A833620A")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface IGreeting
    {
        string SayHello();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("TestDLL.Greeting")]
    [Guid("73D4187A-F71D-4E45-832A-6DD9F88CC59B")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class Greeting : IGreeting
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public string SayHello()
        {
            return "Hello, World!";
        }
    }
}
```

A WinForms project added to the solution successfully calls the SayHello() method.

TestDLL project properties:
Application / Target Framework - .NET Framework 4
Application / Assembly Information / Make assembly COM-visible: false (I only want certain public classes within the assembly to be COM-visible, not ALL public classes. Even though for this demo there's just one class and I do want it to be COM-visible. The code above should have taken care of that.)
Application / Assembly Information / Title and Description and Company and Product are all "TestDLL".
Build / Platform: Active (any CPU)
Build / Platform target: x86
Build / Register for COM interop: false (I don't want it to work on MY computer only but ALL computers. Thus I want to register the assembly when it is INSTALLED, not when it is BUILT.)
Signing / Sign the assembly: false (I want the assembly to live in the install folder, not in the GAC.)

A peek at AssemblyInfo.cs reveals:

```
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: Guid("6bf701f9-3953-43bb-a8af-1bdf7818af3c")]
```

The assembly is built.
Then a type library is created using the Visual Studio Command Prompt (run as Administrator) with this command:

```
tlbexp "C:\(path)\bin\Release\TestDLL.dll" /win32 /out:"C:\(path)\bin\Release\TestDLL.tlb"
```

A Visual Studio Installer project called SetupTestDLL is added to the solution.
On its File System tab, Application Folder, TestDLL.dll is added. This automatically also adds TestDLL.tlb.
Right-clicking TestDLL.dll in that Application Folder allows opening a properties window.
There, Register: vsdraCOM
When right-clicking TestDLL.tlb in that Application folder to get the properties window:
Register: vsdrfCOM
(I'm guessing that vsdraCOM means register the assembly and vsdrfCOM means register a file for COM.)
One more file is added to the Application folder: TestDLL.pdb.

SetupTestDLL is built.
Browsing to its output folder, reveals setup.exe and setupTestDLL.msi.
Right-click setup.exe and Run as administrator.
A dialog box displays the correct install path and the correct "Install for everyone" option.
The install completes successfully.

In the Control Panel / Programs and Features, TestDLL is now listed. Its publisher is listed as "XYZ". Where did that come from? Evidently from the "Manufacturer" property of the SetupTestDLL project's property window. I created that value only there in the entire solution.

In C:\Program Files (x86) there is now an "XYZ" folder, under which is a TestDLL folder, and in that are the three files.

Launch MS Access. Open an existing database and its existing code module.
From the Access code window toolbar, choose Tools / References.
TestDLL is found in the Available References listbox. Click its check box and click OK.

Click the Object Browser button on the code window toolbar.
 is selected in a dropdown list. Change it to TestDLL.
The class "Greeting" is shown with its method "SayHello". So far, so good.
Close the Object Browser.
Create this procedure in the code module and try to run it.

```
Public Sub Test2()
    '    Dim o As New TestDLL.Greeting 
    ' The above is early binding. It should also work 
    ' since we set a reference.
    Dim o As Variant
    Set o = CreateObject("TestDLL.Greeting")
    ' The above is late binding.
    Debug.Print o.SayHello()
    Set o = Nothing
End Sub
```

Result:
Whether early or late bound,
ActiveX Component can't create object.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was just going to add a comment, but I don't have enough reputation points so I'll just post this as an answer and remove it if necessary.

I'm not familiar with Visual Studio Installer projects, so I'm not sure if it is registering the assembly correctly.  Have you tried using regasm to register TestDLL?  Something like:

```
regasm /codebase TestDLL.dll /tlb:TestDLL.tlb
```

Comment: I'm trying not to use regasm. I want to know how to make an installer that does it all. If I wanted the DLL to work on my computer only, I could check a box in the project properties that would register the DLL when I build it. But that wouldn't leave me with an install package useful elsewhere.

Comment: I was able to call the dll from classic ASP but I had to check the "Register for COM Interop" box, set the IIS Application pool to allow 32-bit apps, and also give IIS permission on the Visual Studio projects folder.

Answer (score 0):

64-bit MS Office cannot use a 32-bit COM DLL early bound, but with a reg hack involving DLLSurrogate, it can use it late-bound. I got that to work.

Comment: It can, just cannot load it in-proc. DCOM lets you work this around.

Comment: In-proc means early-bound? I did get it to work late-bound by using a reg hack regarding "DLLSurrogate". I thought DCOM was just for setting permissions.

Comment: In-proc can be either early or late binding. DCOM is very cool - it can help with permissions, it can help with leaks, it can help with bitness differences.